# CSS Pie Slices Unable To Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have recently been trying to work on css pie menu. Everything works fine, except **the hover doesn't work if the slices are more than 9 parts**. For clearer picture, visit [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lightofindia1/sLokghwo/).

The following is my html:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="menu-items">
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-support"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my css:

```
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css);
html,
body {
    color: #000;
}

.menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: -60px;
    top: -60px;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:0.01em solid #455A64;
    background-color: #3F51B5;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.menu .menu-btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    transition:0.1s linear all;
}
.menu:hover .menu-btn{
    font-size:24px;
    right:28px;
    bottom: 28px;
}

.menu-items {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color:#fff;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /*display:none;*/
}

.menu-item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -o-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
    cursor:pointer;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
    transform: rotate(112.5deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
    transform: rotate(157.5deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(202.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(202.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(202.5deg);
    transform: rotate(202.5deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(247.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(247.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(247.5deg);
    transform: rotate(247.5deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(10) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(292.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(292.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(292.5deg);
    transform: rotate(292.5deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(11) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(315deg);
    transform: rotate(315deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(12) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(337.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(337.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(337.5deg);
    transform: rotate(337.5deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(13) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(14) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(382.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(382.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(382.5deg);
    transform: rotate(382.5deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(15) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(405deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(405deg);
    transform: rotate(405deg);
}
.menu-item:nth-child(16) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(427.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(427.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(427.5deg);
    transform: rotate(427.5deg);
}
.menu-item-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -o-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    clip: rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px);
    background-color: #1b458b;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
    transform: rotate(22.5deg);
}
.menu-item .menu-item-content i{
    position:absolute;
    top:12px;
    left:77px;
    font-size: 16px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.menu-item .menu-item-content:hover, .menu-item .active {
    background-color : #1976D2 !important;
}
```

If possible, there is another problem. If you can observe in the demo, **after every 4 parts the border is missing**. Please help me with these problems.

Comment: The hover doesn't work because you are using 200x200px squares and they are overlapping on top of each other thus the bottom ones are under the top ones.

Comment: This sort of design screams out for SVG.

Comment: @IvanKovachev Any suggestions on correcting it?

Comment: @Paulie_D I have no knowledge about svg :( Anyways, it works fine except for these issues.

Comment: Either SVG as Paulie suggested or you can experiment with placing and rotating smaller rects eg 200x50px - this way they'll have little overlap at the center. You can also put bigger transparent divs under the icon and trigger their hover, but again the center of the pie will not trigger. The main issue is that html dom elements are rects thats why SVG is better approach here because you can have areas. Another suggestion is to go with <canvas> and build the items with arcs.

Comment: @IvanKovachev I will surely try experimenting. And I will try learning SVG and Canvas too.

Comment: Changing rectangle sizes did not work :(

Comment: And guys, any idea about the missing borders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `menu-item` class to

```
.menu-item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -o-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    clip: rect(0px, 138px, 100px, 100px);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css);
html,
body {
  color: #000;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: -60px;
  top: -60px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.01em solid #455A64;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.1s linear all;
}

.menu:hover .menu-btn {
  font-size: 24px;
  right: 28px;
  bottom: 28px;
}

.menu-items {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*display:none;*/
}

.menu-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  clip: rect(0px, 138px, 100px, 100px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  transform: rotate(112.5deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  transform: rotate(157.5deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(202.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(202.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(202.5deg);
  transform: rotate(202.5deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(247.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(247.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(247.5deg);
  transform: rotate(247.5deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(292.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(292.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(292.5deg);
  transform: rotate(292.5deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(315deg);
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(337.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(337.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(337.5deg);
  transform: rotate(337.5deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(13) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(14) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(382.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(382.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(382.5deg);
  transform: rotate(382.5deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(15) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(405deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(405deg);
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(16) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(427.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(427.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(427.5deg);
  transform: rotate(427.5deg);
}

.menu-item-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px);
  background-color: #1b458b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  transform: rotate(22.5deg);
}

.menu-item .menu-item-content i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 77px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.menu-item .menu-item-content:hover,
.menu-item .active {
  background-color: #1976D2 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="menu-items">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-support"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-content"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, its finally works :) But can you help me with the border problem too?

Comment: Took me almost one and half hours to reach to the solution. What is the problem with the borders?

Comment: After every 4 parts, the border is missing :(

Comment: Try this 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLokghwo/6/)

`.menu-item-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 204px;
   margin-left: -0.6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px);
  background-color: #1b458b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  transform: rotate(22.5deg);
}`

Comment: You are genius buddy! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: HI @Manikiran bro, plz give me my bounty

Comment: Oh sorry bro, I thought accepting the answer would give away the bounty. Thanks once again!

Comment: Thanks bro, I am also new here, no problem.